# Generadores anidados: se termina la ejecución antes de lo esperado

Tags: javascript, nodejs, generador

Estoy haciendo una pruebas con generadores, para dividir una cadena en *tokens*. Pero el resultado obtenido no es el esperado:

```js
function *stringIterator( str ) {
    for( const ch of str ) {
        yield ch
    }
}

function parseString( iterator ) {
    var value = '';

    for( const ch of iterator ) {
        if( ch == "'" ) { break; }

        value += ch;
    }

    return { value };
}

function *tokenGenerator( input ) {
    iterator = stringIterator( input );

    for( const ch of iterator ) {
        switch( ch ) {
        case "'":
            yield parseString( iterator );
            break;
        }
    }
}

for( const token of tokenGenerator( "'hola, mundo''hadios'" ) ) {
    console.log( token );
}
```

El valor obtenido por consola es

> { value: 'hola, mundo' }

Sin embargo, lo que yo espero obtener es

> { value: 'hola, mundo' }
> { value: 'adios' }

Hay 3 funciones implicadas, siendo 2 de ellas *generadores* y la tercena una función *normal*:

1. `function *stringIterator( )`

   Generador que recorre una cadena, devolviendo un carácter cada vez.
2. `function parseString( )`

   Función normal que, usando la primera, ha de acumular caracteres en una cadena, y devolver la cadena acumulada cuando el carácter encontrado sea un `'` (comilla simple).
3. `function *tokenGenerator( )`

   Función generadora que crea un generador (`1`) a partir de una cadena y **debería** llamar repetidas veces a `2`.

Por los resultados obtenidos, parece que tanto `1` como `2` funcionan correctamente, fallando `3` (o mi forma de llamarla).

- ¿ Que estoy haciendo mal ?
- ¿ Cómo lo soluciono ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es que dentro de `parseString()` estás iterando nuevamente con `for(...)` y "rompes" el ciclo del generador.

Dentro de un ciclo *while* hay que continuar iterando con `.next()` para conservar la funcionalidad del generador, sabiendo que la función devuelve un resultado con dos propiedades: `value`, para cada valor en iteración y `done`, verdadero cuando finaliza o falso cuando aún quedan valores pendientes.

Referencia: [Yield - Descripción](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/yield#Descripci%C3%B3n)

```js
function *stringIterator( str ) {
    for( const ch of str ) {
        yield ch
    }
}

function parseString( iterator ) {
    var value = '';
    while(true) {
        // Obtener resultado para analizar
        let resp = iterator.next();
        // Terminó la iteración o es caracter de "fin"?
        if(resp.done || resp.value == "'") {
            // Salir del ciclo
            break;
        }
        // Agregar caracter actual a cadena
        value += resp.value;
    }
    return { value };
}

function *tokenGenerator( input ) {
    iterator = stringIterator( input );

    for( const ch of iterator ) {
        switch( ch ) {
        case "'":
            yield parseString( iterator );
            break;
        }
    }
}

for( const token of tokenGenerator( "'hola, mundo''hadios'" ) ) {
    console.log( token );
}
```